# Percentage calculation

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, percentage

I following Nassen et al. calculations and I am not sure how the increase why the author suggests a reduction of work time by one percent would increase energy use by 0.24% and the greenhouse gas emissions by 0.20%. How this is calculated

[image]

Comment: Presumably they multiplied the marginal minutes in the second column by the intensities in the third and fourth columns to get changes in total energy or CO2 for a $60$ minute change. They may have adjusted this by a factor of $60$ minutes/hour.  The baseline figure comes from the first column multiplied by the third or fourth columns, again possibly adjusted by a factor of $60$ minutes/hour.  You then want to consider a $1\%$ change which represents $0.151$ minutes per hour.

Comment: The signs come because it seems all non-work activities are on average more energy and CO2 intensive then work (and the bus/train commuting savings are very small)